# Data Integration - super Badge #9 Issue

Tags: apex, integration, superbadges

I have created external data source named **BillingService** with all the other options as mentioned.

Then, I validated and sync it which created **invoices** exteranl object.

I created Indirect lookup relationship with the **project**.

When I see check challenge, I am facing following error

[image: Challenge Not yet complete...]

Here is my external data source and Invoice object

[image: External Data Source Configuration]

[image: External Object Configuration]

Comment: Looks like you are missing some steps, visit the challenge again to identify if you had made all the respective changes.

Comment: I have completed all the challenges except this last one.. 
How come i miss the step. 
All the steps with respect to this I have mentioned. 
Pls let me know if any step you find missing.

Comment: This issue is fixed now , please verify .

Comment: Yes, This is fixed now

Answer (score 1):

It's the known issue from the API and the support team has fixed this. Here is [twitter thread](https://twitter.com/jeffdonthemic/status/856903612831813632) saying same.

Comment: Please provide a link if that is the case...

Comment: That's the reply from askforce in one of the tweet regarding this.

Comment: Can you [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/171591/edit) in a link to the tweet, or to a known issue document?